# Can traffic conditions be ignored when generating directions in bing maps web control API?

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

For our application we are presenting route options to a user that will be used for planning purposes (distance, time, etc). Is there a way, with the bing maps web control api, to ignore traffic conditions? For example, if a major highway is closed at the time the directions are generated, I don't want to route around that. Other conditions are fine, such as highway or non-highway, or possibly just other options that are similar. But we don't want to change the route options based on current traffic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the routeOptimization option in the directionsRequestOptions to shortestTime. I believe that is the default. The calculated route will be based on posted speed limits and not on traffic conditions. The response includes two times, one with and one without traffic for the route path.